# Errors running scanf(), tute uses gets()

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm working on a question for a course at my school. I can't seem to use `scanf()` for some reason, and I've got to use `gets()`.

The question is as follows:

Write a C function `stringncpy()` that copies not more
than n characters (characters that follow a null character
are not copied) from the array pointed to by `s2` to the
array pointed to by `s1`.

If the array pointed to by `s2` is
a string shorter than n characters, null characters
are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by
`s1`, until n characters in all have been written.

The
`stringncpy()` returns the value of `s1`.

**The function
prototype:**

```
char *stringncpy(char * s1, char * s2, int n);
```

In addition, write a C program to test the `stringncpy`
function. Your program should read the string and the
target n characters from the user and then call the
function with the user input.

In this program, you are
**not allowed to use any functions from the C standard
String library**

When I run the program after a successful build, I keep getting the following error.

```
Enter the string:
this is atest
Enter the number of characters:
stringncpy(): ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠this
```

The code for the implementation is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
char *stringncpy(char *s1, char *s2, int n);
int main()
{
    char sourceStr[40], targetStr[40], *target;
    int length;
    printf("Enter the string: \n");
    //scanf("%s",sourceStr); //doesn't work for some reason
    gets(sourceStr); 
    printf("Enter the number of characters: \n");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    target = stringncpy(targetStr, sourceStr, length);
    printf("stringncpy(): %s\n", target);
    return 0;
}
char *stringncpy(char *s1, char *s2, int n)
{
    /* Copy source to target */
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (s2[i] == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            s1[i] = s2[i];
        }
    }
    //s1[i + 1] = '\0';
    for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        s1[j] = '\0';
    }
    return s1;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this?
Thank you.

Comment: Read *carefully* the documentation of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and of [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Some systems (e.g. POSIX) have [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html). Compile your code with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). **Use the debugger** `gdb` and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Your fix-my-code question (or do-my-homework one) is **off-topic**.

Comment: **Don't use `gets`** : it is dangerous and obsolete.

Comment: Note that [`gets()` is to dangerous to be used — ever!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Comment: What keys did you type before the first `t` and after the last `t` in `"this is atest"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `gets`; it's deprecated. **Use `fgets` instead.**

The following loop seems to violate the following requirement:

> If the array pointed to by s2 is a string shorter than n characters, null characters are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by s1, until n characters in all have been written.
>
> ```
> for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
> {
>     s1[j] = '\0';
> }
> ```

This is causing n+1 characters to be written. Is it possible that this is causing an off-by-one (buffer overflow), which is undefined behaviour, and likely to cause illogical behaviour?

It's also important to note that **`scanf` returns a value**, which if you were to validate you'd have spotted an error early on!

That error is, **`scanf("%s", ...)` is not analogous to `gets(...)`**. `gets` reads a *line* of input, while it's more appropriate to think of `scanf("%s", ...)` as though it reads a *word* (whitespace delimitered token) of input.

Logic follows that if your input is `"Hello world\n"` followed by `"13\n"`, `gets` would read `"Hello world\n"` into `sourceStr`, then `"13\n"` would be left in `stdin` to be assigned to `length` by `scanf` later.

On the other hand, if you use `scanf("%s", ...)` then `"Hello"` will be read into `sourceStr`, and `"world\n" "13\n"` will be left in `stdin` to be... **wait, how do you convert `"world\n"` to a decimal integer?** Is this also likely to cause illogical behaviour?

**Check your return value!** This is important for `fgets`, too. Since both of your calls to `scanf` expect one field, they should both return 1 when successful. e.g.

```
int x = scanf("%s", sourceStr);
if (x != 1) { /* XXX: something went wrong! */ }

x = scanf("%d", &length);
if (x != 1) { /* XXX: something went wrong! */ }
```

If you really must use `scanf` to read a line, the appropriate conversion specification would be `%[^\n]`, which like `%s` has similar issues to `gets` (namely, it doesn't know the size of the target array, so it might cause overflows). You should prefix the specifier with a length, which involves using magic numbers (e.g. `%39[^\n]` in your case). Better to just **use the best tool for the job**, which in this case is `fgets`.

Comment: I would suggest that [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) is better than `fgets`. But only defined in POSIX

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I consider the desirable qualities represented by the word "better" to be "able to use on systems outside of POSIX" and "able to use with automatic storage duration, as opposed to "locking us into allocated storage duration". `argv` is likely more suitable yet, as this wouldn't place an explicit limit in size, fulfilling the only desirable quality of `getline`. Nonetheless, thanks for your two cents. That was a very valuable pedantic note.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your inputs,

Enter the string:
this is atest
Enter the number of characters:
stringncpy(): ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠this

it is clear that it didn't give you the chance to enter a number.
This means that, as above answer indicated, the characters after the 
first white space stayed in the stdin buffer and it was automatically
assigned to the variable 'length'.

So you want to check out the value that is assigned to variable "length".

In this case string was assigned to an int variable and we got this weird results.

Here is another way of getting an integer value from a user prompt:

```
printf("Enter the number of characters: \n");
fgets( sLength, 10, stdin );
length = atoi(sLength);
```

When you use scanf(),  the problem with this approach is that the Carriage Return character stays in STDIN buffer.

Answer (score -1):

scanf("%s",sourceStr); doesn't work with the strings which has spaces or newline characters in them.
As you have given the input
"This is a text."

**you have to make use of scanset
or gets function**

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",sourceStr);
```

this will read the whole string along with spaces until a newline character is encountered.

Comment: **`gets` is obsolete** (removed from C11) **and dangerous**. It should *never* be recommended.

Comment: But that is not a good reason: you need to read about *undefined behavior*

Comment: but what about scanset, that can be used without any worry, right?

Comment: `scanset` is not standard (my Linux distribution don't have it)

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",sourceStr);` is wrong (the 's' shouldn't be there).  And `scanf("%[^\n]", sourceStr);` has the same flaw as `gets(sourceStr);` -- a maximum width should be given to overcome that (eg. `scanf("%39[^\n]", sourceStr);`.

Comment: @Dmitri `scanf("%[^\n]", sourceStr);` also has a problem when the first character is `'\n'`, as the function returns without putting anything in `sourceStr`,

Comment: @chux that's what it is supposed to do.

Comment: It does not even put a null character in `sourceStr` when the first character read is `'\n'`.  Without checking the return value of `scanf()`, code  should not use `sourceStr`.  Quality code does not use `scanf("%[^\n]s",sourceStr);` nor `scanf("%[^\n]",sourceStr);`.

Comment: @chux so according to you , what should be used?

Comment: To read a _line_ of input, use `fgets()`.  OP is unfortunately obliged to use `gets()`, a function that has not been part of standard C for 6 years.